# How to call functions when swipe the List up or down in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to call functions when user use the List. Like autoplay video when swiping the List to show the video in screen.

onAppear can't work in right way. It will work when list appear.

```
.onAppear(perform: { })
```

Comment: Add a drag gesture as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66548818/7129318). Then use `.onChanged()` or `.onEnded()` depending in your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simultaneousGesture method. Example:

List {
// Items for the list view
}
.simultaneousGesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ _ in
// Do anything when user drag inside list view.
}))